# 'No module named openpyxl', cannot import event though module is installed. I have never had this issue with other modules

Tags: python

I have been following through the Automate the Boring Stuff Book and have had little trouble up until now. I have installed all of the other modules using

`sudo pip install some_module`

Trying to install openpyxl has been the first time that there is an issue. I have spent ~2 hours trying to fix this problem, but with little success.

I think the problem may lie with the PATH, but do not understand it enough to start messing around with it just it and possibly create more problems.

```
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

Comment: FYI installing Python modules with `sudo pip install` is not recommended. You should use [a virtual environment instead](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/). Anyway, did the command succeed?

Comment: What version of Python do you have? Are there multiple versions on your PC? What was the result from the attempted sudo pip install?

Comment: What is the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: The out put of pip freeze is: openpyxl ==2.6.2